# jquery select li element in hierarchical menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to get the text from the certain `li` when it is clicked on, code is below:

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
       <li>list item 3</li>
       <li>list item 4</li>
       <li>list item 5</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>list item 6</li>
    <li>
       <ul>
       <li>list item 7</li>
       <li>list item 8</li>
       <li>list item 9t</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this case, I need to get the "*list item 5*" by its index.

Edited:

Basically, when the `<li>list item 5</li>` is clicked i want to get this particallar text or value, when something else is clicked - do nothing. Note that although the menu is hierarchical, 5th element means flat 5th element. Carefully check the texts of the `li` items to understand.

Comment: can't you just give it specific class or id?

Comment: Welcome Marcel - Stackoverflow tries to gather and answer common questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best solution is to give that item an id or, at least, a class then you can do:

```
$("#myID").click(function() {
    var text=$(this).text();
});
```

If you can't do this, then you can try using the various navigation selectors, maybe something like (untested):

```
$("div>ul>li:nth-child(3)>ul>li:nth-child(3)").click(...
```

But this is a really awkward way to do it and may break the second you add any more items to your list(s). (here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DvCdK/) - it'll alert only when your *list item 5* is clicked)

Or if the text is static, you could select by that:

```
$("li:contains('list item 5')").click(...
```

Which, again, will break if that text changes, or if there are other nodes that contain the same text.

Comment: hmm...yes, but this applies to every 3rd element, so if you had 9 main ul's that would be applied 3rd, 6th, 9th, which i don't want.

Comment: text should by dynamic though :(

Comment: @Marcel: No it won't. It only applies to the 3rd - you are thinking of `:nth-child(3n)`. But using the direct descendant selector (`>`) might be better.

Comment: amazing, thanks..will this be ok for older IE versions? As i know they sometimes don't like (>) selectors

Comment: @Marcel: It *should* be okay with IE. JQuery will make the necessary changes if a browser doesn't support some feature.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BAG23/1/)**

Comment: Not only does this not do what the OP wanted (although the question was far from clear), it let's the clicks bubble so you get multiple alerts when you click one of the nested `li`.

Comment: @MattBurland I updated jsfiddle to stop bubbling. OP edited question so now this answer is no more accurate for what OP wants (at this time because maybe OP will re-edit his question again & again & again...)

Answer (score 3):

Well, it appears that `eq` selector is sufficient for your purpose.

```
$("li:eq(5)").click(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
})
```

Comment: without adding any classes or id's...somethin based on .eq() or index?

Comment: @Marcel: You mean, although the list has hierarchy, you want them to be treated as flat for this purpose? I think that will be difficult with a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```